# Algorithm to compare one array of strings to many array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

I am a bit stuck on this one problem in the current project I am working on:

I want to take one `ArrayList<String>` (call it **A**) and compare it to **many** `ArrayList<String>`, making note of how many strings match in these array comparisons. Then, I want to order the multiple string arrays in order from most similar to least similar to A.

Does anyone know any fast algorithms to do this? Not looking for code so much as algorithms, but I am working in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: What's with the close vote reasons? How is this "asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource"?

Comment: You will be using hash values, probably in several different ways.  (And actually, this question is a dupe -- it gets asked maybe once every 2 weeks.)

Comment: oops, sorry for the duplicate! couldn't find the question around, but I was probably not looking in the right place. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I'm too lazy to look up the dupe, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion :

1. First put all the Strings of the reference ArrayList in a Set.
2. Go over all the members of each of the other ArrayLists, and using `set.contains(string)` find out how many matches each array list contains.
3. For each ArrayList, create an object that wraps an ArrayList in addition to the number of matches for that ArrayList.
4. Finally, sort those wrapper objects according to the number of matches.

Comment: And make objects that wrap `ArrayList` + match count implement `Comparable` to be able to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the similarity (or difference) between strings then try an edit distance algorithm such as the Levenshtein distance algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Levenshtein_distance